# setup.py installing package and script - NameError referencing package from script

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm struggling with my first Python package + script project using `setuptools`. Here's a skeleton of my `setup.py`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name=<PROJECT>,
    packages=[<PACKAGE_NAME>],
    scripts=['bin/<PACKAGE_NAME>.py'],
    python_requires='>=3',
)
```

My package is in `package_name/` and my script, which has the same base name as the package, is in `bin/package_name.py`. The script does `from package_name import *`. There are no dependencies.

When I run `python3 setup.py install`, it succeeds. Thereafter, when I do `import package_name` in a Python console, it succeeds. But when I run the script from the command line, it fails with a `NameError` on the first reference to a component from the package. I've reproduced the same error on Mac OS X and Linux.

Why does it fail this way, but doesn't throw an `ImportError`? How can I fix my script or my `setup.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has the same base name as the package

That's exactly the problem. When you run `package_name.py` and the script imports `package_name` Python tries to import it from that script because it's the first `package_name.py` in `sys.path` (Python automatically prepends script's directory to `sys.path`).

Rename the script to `package_name`. Or even better create [`__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html?#module-__main__) in your package and use [`entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords):

```
setup(
    …
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'package_name = package_name.__main__:main'
        ]
    },
    …
)
```

That way `setuptools` create the script `package_name` for you automatically.

See an example in my [mimedecode](https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode).

Comment: Thank you - that solved the problem, and taught me something about Python's import order.

Placing command-line scripts in `__main__.py` inside the package seems like it break the separability of library and client. I'd say that wasn't great practice in C, but I don't know Python as well. Is that the preferred way to distribute such a package (library + its own client)?

Comment: Yes. Or, if it's a one-module (not-package) library it usually has its own `main()` function, protected with `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Even modules in Python library have these. [Example: zipfile.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipfile.py#L2025).